# Handling multiple requests without previous one blocking the next one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have problems trying to handle multiple requests from the client. By right, each route should be handled asynchronously, however I can't make handling request after request without the previous one blocking the next one. With the following code I am using promises and using Express.js router

```
  let api = Router();

  api.get('/a', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('A: get all A');
    getAllA()
      .then(() => console.log('A: finish retrieving A'));
    console.log('A: do something else');
  });

  api.get('/b', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('B: get all B');
    getAllB()
      .then(() => console.log('B: finish retrieving B')
    console.log('B: do something else');
  });
```

So if I request */a* and then */b* almost instantly after, the output **currently** is:

```
// Request /a
'A: get all A'
'A: do something else'
// Request /b
'A: finish retrieving A'
'B: get all B'
'B: do something else'
'B: finish retrieving B'
```

While I **expect** it to be something like this:

```
// Request /a
'A: get all A'
'A: do something else'
// Request /b
'B: get all B'
'B: do something else'
'A: finish retrieving A'
'B: finish retrieving B'
```

Any idea whether this is expected or there are other ways to handle this?

Comment: What do `getAllA` and `getAllB` do? Do they perform asynchronous I/O or have you mocked them up with `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` or something? Remember that node.js, like JavaScript in the browser, is single-threaded. It might be that you request /a, and if `getAllA` uses `setTimeout` or `setImmediate` then after all I/O is processed those callbacks will be processed. Then the next event loop ticks over and the next request is processed.

Comment: Additionally, if by "asynchronously" you are assuming that the routes will be processed in parallel at the same time, then that's not true, because as I said the JavaScript event loop is single-threaded.

Comment: you don't have to handle multiple request manually. Just make sure `getAllA()` and `getAllB()` is not blocking your IO, i mean they should be asynchronous .

Comment: Thanks for the input. You are right, these two functions still ran on the single thread instead of doing async I/O. A little better understanding on concurrency in node.js thanks to you! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node.js server runs only one Javascript thread of execution at a time.  It does not actually process multiple requests at the exact same time.  So, if one request hogs the CPU for awhile, no other requests will get processed until that first request finishes and gives up the CPU.

But, if your requests do async operations (async file I/O, async networking, set timers to do something in the future, use some third party library that implements some other async operation, etc...), then whenever a request starts an async operation and returns control back to the event queue, then another request can start processing until it finishes or also hits an async operation.  Whether it does or doesn't will depend entirely on the timing of things.  In this way, multiple requests can be "in-flight" at the same time, even though only one is ever actually running Javascript at a time.

So, in your code, it really depends upon what `getAllA()` and `getAllB()` are doing.  If they are synchronous operations, then they will block other threads while they run.  If they are asynchronous operations, but they content for the same resources (such as a database or file or server), then they may still cause some serialization because of the mutual dependency upon the availability of an external resource.

One way to get true parallel request processing in node.js is with clustering.  With node.js clustering, you start up multiple node.js processes on the same computer (usually about the same number of processes as CPU cores you have) and then each node.js process can independently process requests in parallel.  If you have shared resources that all the processes in the cluster must access, then you will still have to find a way to share those across processes (database, custom central repository of shared info, redis, etc..).

For example, you could see multiple requests in flight at the same time if you did something like this:

```
let api = Router();

api.get('/a', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('start of a');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('done with a');
        res.json({status: "ok", msg: "done with a"});
    }, 500);
});

api.get('/b', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('start of b');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('done with b');
        res.json({status: "ok", msg: "done with b"});
    }, 500);
});
```

If you then fire off requests for /a and for /b right after one another, you should get this in the server console:

```
start of a
start of b
done with a
done with b
```

Both requests were "in-flight" at the same time, though not actually executing Javascript at the same time.  Note: I used `setTimeout()` just to simulate an async operation with a known and controllable response time.  That can be any series of asynchronous operations.

Comment: Wow, really great explanation. Initially, I thought that as long as I use Promises, it will make the `getAllA()` and `getAllB()` asynchronous, but I misunderstood that whatever is inside them will still run on the main thread, just that the execution of these will be asynchronous. Thank you greatly for this elaborated explanation, I suppose I will start by using clusters instead of trying to run the code inside these functions on the thread pool; however that still would be a viable option. Thank you again